# Is it possible to overload template classes in c++?

Tags: c++

I'm currently creating some utilities for my projects, and I came up with the idea to replicate the C# `Action` class in C++. As you can see in the [C# documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action?view=net-7.0), the `Action` class can have different "overloads" with templates. It has `Action`, `Action<T1>`, `Action<T1, T2\>`, etc.

Is it possible to overload classes like this in C++? Or, is there any workaround?

This is an example of "pseudocode", C++ throws a syntax error with this:

```cpp
class Action
{
    // Code
};

template<class T1>
class Action
{
    // Code
};

template<class T1, class T2>
class Action
{
    // Code
};

// etc...
```

So that you can call different kinds of classes depending if you input a template or not, like this:

```cpp
int main()
{
    Action a1;
    Action<int> a2;
    Action<int, float> a3;
    // etc...

    return 0;
}
```

I tried various things, such as:

```
template<T1, T2>
class Action {};

template<T1, T2>
class Action<T1.> {};

template<T1, T2>
class Action<T1, T2> {};
```

But this does not work.

Comment: You can make a variadic template and then specialize it for certain numbers of arguments. Or, even better, just make a variadic template.

Comment: No, you cannot. You can have default template arguments, though, like `template<typename T1, typename T2 = void, typename T3 = void> class Action { ......... };`. You can also do template specialization to handle cases with `T3=void` or `T2=void` in a special way. You can also do variadic templates like `template<typename... Ts> class Action { ........ };`.

Comment: There is nothing in the question that indicates why these things should have the same name. There is no relationship between them, and their names should reflect that. Is there something in `// Code` that would give them some common capabilities?

Comment: I'm not familiar with C#, but it looks  like you need `std::function`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, classes can't be overloaded. `Action` in the scope can be either a single non-templated class or a single class template with a given template head (not different ones).

But, a given class template can be specialized for certain template arguments and there are [variadic templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) since C++11 which accept an arbitrary number of template arguments:

```
template<typename... Ts>
class Action { /* generic case */ };
```

This allows for `a2` and `a3` and via [explicit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) or [partial specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization) they can be specialized for e.g. one or two template arguments:

```
template<typename T1>
class Action<T1> { /* one template argument */ };

template<typename T1, typename T2>
class Action<T1, T2> { /* two template arguments */ };
```

`a1` can also work since C++17 via [class template argument deduction (CTAD)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) depending on which constructors the primary class template has and/or what deduction guides are declared.

---

I don't have enough knowledge of C# or context to know whether this is a useful approach to take for your underlying problem though.

---

Also, as a side note: `class` and `typename` when introducing template parameters in the template head are synonymous. Choose `class` if you prefer that. There is no difference.